# display preview of webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

Tried searching for this and couldn't find much. Is there a package jQuery or otherwise that can present a small preview of a linked website.

I'd like to be able to more or less display a small feed of linked content for each sub niche on a social platform I'm creating. As an example let's say I wanted to link to a news website and display a live feed of updates in a niche of say tech updates for example almost akin to a live twitter feed plugin.

This would probably kill performance. Nonetheless, thought it was a cool idea and wondering if there's anything packages out there I can try this out with.

Comment: You could iFrame in the page and then resize it to be smaller with css.

It's definitely not a good idea.

Comment: This can now be achieved with JavaScript using. I haven't used it yet but I'm planning on - https://github.com/cjdell/webpage-preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if that news website provides an API to fetch news, you can keep making AJAX requests to their API URLs at regular intervals to retrieve latest news.

But if that website doesn't provide any API, make AJAX requests to your server, then at your server do some web-scraping and return the news to the AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is using HTML iFrame.

I would not recommend it though - loading your website would take a long time (because X iFrames needs to load as well).